# Can we use both "gonna" and "wanna" together?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, formality

For instance, can we say "I'm gonna wanna do it".
or is it better to say "I am going to want to do it".
It shouldn't be grammatically incorrect, but can we consider this is not common even in informal way.

Comment: Yes, you can say it. "Gonna" and "wanna" are very clearly informal as spellings, but not as pronunciations. The "am" would probably also be contracted: "I'm gonna wanna do it," and in writing you would use "I'm going to want to do it."

Comment: Nobody who says "gonna" or "wanna" is going to say "i am" in the same sentence.

Comment: @phoog Yes, you are right. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm gonna wanna do it" is a common informal usage, verbally.

It would only be used in writing if quoting or reporting a verbal use.

Comment: Meh ... Kinda trite.